# Hive Regex Pattern Issue

Tags: sql, regex, string, hive

My data is having 3 column values something like this-

```
1111 some input $in put1
1121 -          $in put2
```

Between the first value and second there is a space delimiter. In between the second and third columns, there is a space AND a "$" delimiter.
The second value in the second row is not provided so it is just a dash (-).

My table statement in Hive is as below-

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(someid string,something1 string, something2 string) 
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
"input.regex"="^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+.(.+)$",
"output.format.string"="%1$s %2$s %3$s")
stored as textfile;
```

The results I am getting out of it is -

```
1111    Some input  $in put1
1121    -  $in      put2
```

What I am expecting is -

```
1111    Some input  in put1
1121    -           in put2
```

If the second value is just a dash (-) then it is to be taken as a value for the second column.
In the last column, I do not want any delimiter symbol.

What wrong I am doing in the regex. I like to have the same S pattern regex. Please help.

Comment: "3 column values".  You have 5 strings.  The data format is highly not obvious.

Comment: Yeah I mean, it's dummy data and there's no log in this format. However, I'm trying to learn regex input patterns for different types of data. I have been good a few times and lost a few times. It's one of them. Spent almost 8 hours on this to convert it into the desired format. No luck.!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
"input.regex"="^(\\S+)\\s+([^$]+)\\$(.+)$"
```

Regex breakdown:

```
^          beginning of the string
(\\S+)     1 to N non-space characters (capturing)
\\s+       1 to N space characters
([^$]+)    1 to N characters other than a literal "$"
\\$        a literal "$"
(.+)       1 to N characters
$          end of the string
```

Comment: No, it returned all null values instead.

Comment: There's a slight change in my question. In between the second and the third column, there is a space and $ delimiter.